# Profiling PHP application in production on IIS 7

Tags: php, iis-7, profiling

I'd like to profile a PHP application in production. My setup is **windows server 2008** with **IIS 7** and **PHP 5.3 in FastCGI**. I know from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4370795/profiling-code-on-production) that **XHProf Profiler** is a good tool but obviously it doesn't work on Windows yet. Should I try with xdebug profiler or has anyone a better suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

http://dev.freshsite.pl/php-extensions/xhprof/file/details/xhprof-0103-for-php-53-vc9.html

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to a Zend Studio license the profiler built into Zend Server is fantastic (check out some screenshots here http://files.zend.com/help/Beta/Zend_Studio_8_0/working_with_the_profiler.htm) - otherwise XDebug and a cache grind app will help (see this http://devzone.zend.com/1139/profiling-php-applications-with-xdebug/)